# MySQL query returning records that match but also ones that do not

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using the standard LAMP environment. I've written a MySQL query which seems to works except for the fact that it returns results that don't fit the condition, as well as results that do.

```
$sql = "SELECT items.code, cats.cat_name, cats.id
        FROM items, cats
        WHERE cats.cat_name LIKE concat('%', items.code, '%') ";
```

The result that is retuned incudes all the matching records (items.code & cats.cat_name) but further down the retreived results it also shows the cat_names that do not match.

Comment: What datatypes are the columns `items.code` and `cat_name`? Btw: this sounds like a strange data model if you are matching a *code* against a *name* column - or really weird naming conventions.

Comment: The datatypes are both varchar(32). Agreed, a strange use of the items.code field ~ the company using the system is using the items.code for a different purpose than was intended. They are a non-profit with a limited budget so cannot afford too much customisation.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that there is at least one row in items where code is null or an empty string. All cats rows will be joined with such a row in items.

Comment: I've added : AND items.code NOT LIKE '' which then gives the expected result. Does this mean that the %Wildcard matches to fields that are empty?

Comment: @johnfox Of course. *%* matches by definition zero or more characters.